# How can I pass parameters to a fixture and use this fixture in a test method?

Tags: python, automation, pytest

I want to pass username, password and email as fixture parameters here:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def create_user(self):
    try:
        assert self.rbac.put_user(username, password, email).status_code == 200
        yield
    except AssertionError:
        assert self.rbac.get_user(username).status_code == 200
        yield
    finally:
        assert self.rbac.delete_user(username).status_code == 200
```

Later I will use this fixture in my test:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("create_user")
def test_assign_delete_user_to_group(self):
"""some code"""
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Googleling `pytest fixture arguments` ... leads f.e. to https://alysivji.github.io/pytest-fixures-with-function-arguments.html  ... did you research?

Comment: or this: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html to supply mutliple sets of arguments after another

Answer (score 0):

Try a factory fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def user_factory(self, request):
    created_users = []

    def create_or_get_user(username):
        try:
            assert self.rbac.put_user(username, password, email).status_code == 200
        except AssertionError:
            assert self.rbac.get_user(username).status_code == 200
        created_users.append(username)

    yield create_or_get_user

    for username in created_users:
        assert self.rbac.delete_user(username).status_code == 200
```

Then use it with

```
def test_assign_delete_user_to_group(self, user_factory):
    """some code"""
    u = user_factory('foo')
    assert u
```

Comment: Btw using the yield syntax for finalizer has been problematic to me when calling apis because the finalizer is not always called if the test fails.